# QGIS - Symbology - auxiliary lines (position of symbol)

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, symbology

After updating QGIS to version 3.28.1 from my old version I´m missing  auxiliary lines in Symbology, that show the position of the symbol relative to the centre (based on anchor points, offset..). I´m attaching pictures from the older version with lines and the newer version without.

Does anyone know if it´s possible tu turn them on? Are they not included in this version, why?

[image: oldest version]

[image: version 3.28.1]

Comment: Looks like it is a bug.